# Form's input default text

Tags: javascript, forms, search, input, field

I desperately need to have my search form's default input text to change based on the user's selection in the form's select input. The current default input text is *Enter Keywords…* and stays the same no matter what option is selected. What I want, for example, is when the user selects **"Employee Directory"** to have the default input text for the search field to change to *Enter Employee's First Name…*

---

This is the desired input fields for each selection:

**"Website"** = *Enter Keywords…*

**"Employee Directory"** = *Enter Employee's First Name…*

**"Publications Center"** = *Enter Publication's Information…*

---

Here is my code as it sits currently:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function dosearch() {
    var sf=document.searchform;
    var submitto = sf.engines.options[sf.engines.selectedIndex].value + escape(sf.s.value) + ((sf.engines.selectedIndex=='1')?('&cat=29'):(''));
    window.location.href = submitto;
    return false;
    }
</script>



<form name="searchform" class="search" method="get" onSubmit="return dosearch();"> 

    <select class="engines" name="engines" id="el08">
        <option value="/?s=" selected>Website</option>
        <option value="/?s=">Publications Center</option>
        <option value="/employee-directory?query=name&contact_dir_s=">Employee Directory</option>
    </select>

    <input name="s" class="input" type="text" value="Enter Keywords..." onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter Keywords...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Enter Keywords...';}" size="18" maxlength="50"> 

    <input type="submit" name="searchsubmit" class="button" value="Go" />

 </form>
```

Anybody with the expertise to help code this or offer suggestions, please do! Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated with code that actually works (only tested in IE). This version notes when the selected search option changes and then updates the input if it was displaying the default prompt that went with the previously selected search option.

```
<body onload="setDefault();">
<form name="searchform" class="search" method="get" onSubmit="return dosearch();">
   <select class="engines" name="engines" id="el08" onchange="setDefault();">
       <option value="/?s=" selected>Website</option>
       <option value="/?s=">Publications Center</option>
       <option value="/employee-directory?query=name&contact_dir_s=">Employee Directory</option>
   </select>
   <input name="s" id="searchBox" class="input" type="text" value="" onfocus="myFocusHandler(this);" onblur="myBlurHandler(this);" size="18" maxlength="50">
   <input type="submit" name="searchsubmit" class="button" value="Go" />
</form> 
</body>
<script>
function myFocusHandler(textField) {
   if (textField.value == defText)
      textField.value = "";
}

function myBlurHandler(textField) {
    if (textField.value == "")
       textField.value = defText;
}

var defText;
var defOptions = {
      "Website" : "Enter keywords...",
      "Employee Directory" : "Enter employee's first name...",
      "Publications Center" : "Enter Publication's Information..."
      // and any other options you may need
      };

function setDefault() {
   var sel = document.getElementById("el08"),
       input = document.getElementById("searchBox"),
       prevDefText = defText;

   defText = defOptions[sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text] || "Enter search term...";
   if (prevDefText == undefined || input.value == prevDefText)
      input.value = defText;
}
</script>
```

Could cut down on use of globals by using a variation of the module pattern or something, but that's an issue for another day.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work out the box, I'll fiddle around with it a bit more tonight. Thank you the help - I'll get back to you later.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, as I said it was untested. I forgot to include code to update the default text when the user changes the selected item. Need to add an `onchange` to the `select` that checks if the `input` is currently displaying the default text for the previously selected search option and if so change it to the text for the newly selected search option. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: It makes perfect sense, I just don't think I'm proficient enough in Javascript to be able to write it! I'm most definitely going to give you the selected answer for this question right now for all of your hard work and, if you have the motivation to, please try and write the other needed code when you get a free moment or two. Thank you again~

Comment: @Eric - I've updated my answer with a version that definitely works (I actually tested this version). Note that in addition to fixing the JavaScript there are a couple of minor changes in the HTML: I added an `onload` to the `body` and an `id` to the `input` element.